# How to import multiple excel sheets into Snowflake database

Tags: excel, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, xlsx, import-from-excel, snowflake-schema

I'm trying to import data from an excel (.xlsx) which has multiple sheets into multiple tables of snowflake.

Ex, if the excel has 3 sheets named product, sales, profit I want load these data from excel into 3 different tables in Snowflake with same (product, sales, profit) or any name.

Any lead towards solution is highly appreciable!!!

Thanks,
Vigneswar

I tried sql commands to import data from Excel to Snowflake, but I was not able to find a way to load data from sheets to table. I have used Put and Copy statement also but I couldn't find option to load from excel sheets.

Solution can be through SQL or Python.

Inputs or leads are highly appreciable!!

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Spin up an Azure tenant, use LogicApps to read the data and save it into a storage account as CSV and then read the file from Snowflake.

Comment: Using python, split xlsx with multiple sheets into separate csv files and then load those csv files in snowflake table (using PUT or usual load options). Refer following from @Quang Hoang for how to separate into multiple csv files - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63291259/converting-excel-file-with-multiple-sheets-into-multiple-csv-files-using-jupyter